# Jfrog API to add users to group incrementally without replacing

Tags: jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, jfrog-mission-control

We are trying to automate JFrog access management using Azuredevops tasks and couldn't find any working solution to update the user addition to the groups in an update passion without replacing existing users from the list.
We are looking for CLI commands or API calls for below scenario.

1. How we can ensure specific user exists in system,
2. adding a existing user to specific group in incremental way. That means, each time when we need to add a user to group, it should add the user to the group without changing any property or already existing users in it.

Answer (score 0):

Both requirements should be possible via the [JFrog Platform REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+REST+API).

1. Check a user exists -
   Use the [get user](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+REST+API#JFrogPlatformRESTAPI-GetUsername) API -

   ```
   GET /access/api/v2/users/{username}
   ```

   Check the response status code - `200` exists, `404` not found.
2. Add a user to a group as a member -
   There are two ways to do that -

   1. [Update the user](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+REST+API#JFrogPlatformRESTAPI-AddorRemoveUserfromGroups) -

      ```
      PATCH /access/api/v2/{username}/groups

      {
        "add": [ "group1" ],
        "remove": [ "group2" ]
      }
      ```
   2. [Update the group](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+REST+API#JFrogPlatformRESTAPI-AddorRemoveaGroupMember) -

      ```
      PATCH /access/api/v2/groups/{name}/members

      {
        "add": [ "user1", "user2" ],
        "remove": [ "user1", "user2" ]
      }
      ```

Comment: Our Jfrog Artifactory version is 7.41.4 and given apis are not working

Comment: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "UNAUTHORIZED",
    "message" : "Unsupported authentication method Basic"
  } ]

Comment: is there any way to achieve this in version 7.41.4 ?

Comment: According to the documentation, these APIs are indeed available from a newer Artifactory version - 7.49.3. I'm not aware of a way to achieve it in an older version. You should anyway upgrade (or move to JFrog SaaS).

Comment: BTW, regarding the "UNAUTHORIZED" error - you'll anyway need to use an access token to use these APIs, as they don't support basic auth.